# Create .msg file from Office 365 Outlook add-in in Javascript or C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Office 365 Outlook add-in and I would like to save any mail in .msg file.

So far, I read this reference : https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/ and didn't find anything that allow me to create .msg file from a mail, in Javascript.

Is it possible to generate a .msg file from javascript?

I use a ASP.NET MVC Web Server (which will be on Azure later) in C# for executing the add-in, so I can use any C# package. I also can't pay for any plugin or library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Office.js library does not let you save the email as .msg format but you can still use the Exchange Web Service from your server to do the job for you.

In [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768988/how-to-get-recurrence-data-from-javascript-api-in-office365/35770085#35770085), I explain how to use EWS library direct from the add-in or from the Web Server.

In your case, I think it would be wiser to do the job on the server and benefit from the .NET EWS SDK rather than struggling locally with SOAP request from javascript.

The question how to save email to .msg using EWS has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293129/save-mail-to-msg-file-using-ews-api).