# Outlook-addin Modify Reminder value of an appointment

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office365api, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an Outlook add-in, the purpose is to create an appointment with its different properties.

Is that possible to modify the value of the reminder field with the Mailbox API? I can't find a method which do that in the documentation (https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/). [image: Reminder field]

Comment: Consider marking an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

When something is not available with Office.js api for an Outlook Add-in you can  try to use the Exchange Web Services (EWS) to do perform the action

Have a look at [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768988/how-to-get-recurrence-data-from-javascript-api-in-office365/35770085#35770085).

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685110/outlook-web-app-exchange-2013-on-premise-api-1-2-how-to-access-email-body/36687542#36687542), I gave code snippets for both (client side or server side approach).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UpdateItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/aa581084(v=exchg.150).aspx) EWS operation to set flag and reminder fields using the [mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/web-services) method:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" soap:mustUnderstand="0" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:UpdateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" ConflictResolution="AlwaysOverwrite">
      <m:ItemChanges>
        <t:ItemChange>
          <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGUzNmEzYTBmLTI1NDItNGE0My1iZDk5LWFkMDgxODI3YWNlOQBGAAAAAACK2VEhi72QSaw+u0XV7xUHBwCMotTyA3QkQ7TPAmcrRt4FAAAALwVDAAAuH/1UA8tzTYD5jbYriaIUAAJEgGbPAAA=" />
          <t:Updates>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Flag" />
              <t:Message>
                <t:Flag>
                  <t:FlagStatus>Flagged</t:FlagStatus>
                  <t:StartDate>2016-02-24T00:00:00.000Z</t:StartDate>
                  <t:DueDate>2016-02-24T00:00:00.000Z</t:DueDate>
                </t:Flag>
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ReminderDueBy" />
              <t:Message>
                <t:ReminderDueBy>2016-02-24T15:00:00.000Z</t:ReminderDueBy>
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ReminderIsSet" />
              <t:Message>
                <t:ReminderIsSet>true</t:ReminderIsSet>
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
            <t:SetItemField>
              <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart" />
              <t:Message>
                <t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>0</t:ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
              </t:Message>
            </t:SetItemField>
          </t:Updates>
        </t:ItemChange>
      </m:ItemChanges>
    </m:UpdateItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today (requirement set 1.3) I don't think there is a method in Office.js which allows you to get or set the reminder field of an appointment. Other people have already mentioned that you may try using EWS call to perform the action.