# Implementing App For Outlook

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2013, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

I have a VSTO Ms Outlook Addin which interacts with Contacts, Tasks, Meetings,Calender and Emails of Outlook and it works fine with Office 2007,2010,2013,2016.

Now, I would like to implement the same for "app for outlook".

How should I do that? Can anyone explain.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can start by consulting this [getting started](https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted).

As a former VSTO add-in dev, you have to rethink the way you design Office add-ins. A web add-in is no more than a web app using a library office.js to fill the bridge between your logic and the office host. Keep in mind that you still have the possibility to use web services to do things that are not available with office.js, see [how here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768988/how-to-get-recurrence-data-from-javascript-api-in-office365/35770085#35770085)

I wrote a [blog post](https://keluro.com/2015/12/08/new-generation-addins-office/) explaining the differences from a technical and business perspective of these two generations of addins.