# Appointment attendees list is not listing by outlook

Tags: office365api, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

**Microsoft Office API** not able to capture the attendees list,if the 
appointment received from **oracle.com** domain (**beehive** mail server).

Appointment created and sent with multiple required and optional attendees from oracle.com domain.Then Logged in into the attendee outlook account and checked the invited calendar appointment,found that attendees list is not showing except logged in user. In add-in also i can't able to get the attendees list from office.js.

Why Outlook native page it self not listing attendees list? Why Office API not listing attendees list for these appointments ? What may be the problem ? Provide the solution to over come it ...

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and it appears to be working. Here is the code I am running in the [API tutorial](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104379630&sourcecorrid=418138db-0d57-48bf-af88-774e66aaa5eb&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false) add-in open for a calendar item where I am an attendee:

showMessage(JSON.stringify(Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees));

Could you please provide some more information on this issue? Which Outlook client and version are you using? Do you see the issue with meeting request message in inbox, or with the calendar item in calendar module, or both? Could you add the code that you're using to get the attendees? Thanks!

Comment: I am using below code to get required attendees                                     
 Office.context.mailbox.item.requiredAttendees;
Here the problem is attendees list is not listing in Native MS Page itself if i got calendar invitation from "@oracle.com" domain mail id.
I am using Desktop client ,version is 16.0.4456.1003. I am encountering the problem with calendar item in calendar module. Thanks.

Comment: We'll check this version. Does it work for you in OWA (Outlook Web App)?

Comment: We could not reproduce the problem with Outlook build 4456. Could you please try in OWA and let us know if that works?

Comment: I've had something similar happen with an invitations. In my case it was because the invite was malformed; a side effect of someone forwarding the invite from one system through another. It may be worth inspecting the payload to make sure it is well formed.

Comment: @ Oleg O ,if appointment received from other domains like gmail.com and live.com then attendees are listing in Outlook and OWA but the problem is if appointment received from oracle.com (beehive server) then atttendees are not listing in Outlook and OWA.

Answer (score -1):

You may be interested in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768988/how-to-get-recurrence-data-from-javascript-api-in-office365/35770085#35770085).

> When something is not available with Office.js api for an Outlook
>   Add-in you can try to use the Exchange Web Services (EWS) to do
>   perform the action

You have basically two ways to request EWS from a mail add-in.

> - You can request directly the EWS with a SOAP request from your client
>     app. See method makeEwsRequestAsync in Office.context.mailbox.
> - You can get an EWS token, send it to your server and make the request from
>     there. Then you can use a EWS SDK server side.

Comment: Benoit,Here the problem is MS exchange not listing the attendees list,means the native outlook page it self not listing the attendees list.

We are not interested to use EWS.